# Chrome says my content script isn't UTF-8

Tags: google-chrome-extension, utf-8, character-encoding, clojurescript

Receiving the error `Could not load file 'worker.js' for content script. It isn't UTF-8 encoded.`

```
> file -I chrome/worker.js
chrome/worker.js: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

With [to-utf8-unix](https://www.npmjs.com/package/to-utf8-unix)

```
> to-utf8-unix chrome/worker.js                                      
chrome/worker.js
----------------
Detected charset:
UTF-8
Confidence of charset detection:
100
Result:
Conversion not needed.
----------------
```

I also tried converting the file with Sublime Text back and forth without any luck.

manifest:

```
  "content_scripts": [{
      "matches": ["http://foo.com/*"],
      "js": ["worker.js"]
  }],
```

The file in question: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kcv23ooh06wlxg3/worker.js?dl=1

It is a compiled javascript file spit out from clojurescript with cljsbuild:

```
               {:id "chrome-worker"
                :source-paths ["src/chrome/worker"],
                :compiler {:output-to "chrome/worker.js",
                           :optimizations :simple,
                           :pretty-print false}}
               ]}
```

Other files (options page, background) are compiled the same way and don't generate this error. I tried getting rid of weird characters like Emojis but that didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Your js file is very large and contains too much unformatted js code. Try to clean it up.

Comment: Might be a bug in this version of Chrome. Try Chrome Canary or an older portable Chrome.

Comment: @elegant-user it doesn't matter if code is minified. Pretty printed has the same problem

Comment: @wOxxOm good thinking! sadly same problem in Canary as well

Answer (score 8):

It turns out this is a problem within the google closure compiler that clojurescript uses to generate javascript - https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/issues/1704

A workaround is to set compilation to "US-ASCII"

```
:closure-output-charset "US-ASCII"
```

Thanks a to to pesterhazy from the clojurians slack for helping with this!

Answer (score 8):

In case you are using Webpack you can solve it by replacing the default minifier **Uglify** with **Terser**, which won´t produce those encoding issues.

in your **webpack.conf.js** add

```
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');

// add this into your config object
optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        parallel: true,
        terserOptions: {
          ecma: 6,
          output: { 
             ascii_only: true 
          },
        },
      }),
    ],
  },
```

Comment: Using this throws an error while building as - Failed to compile.

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'javascript')

Comment: This worked for me. But I don't know why. Why does Ugliy produce encoding issues?

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone has this issue with Parcel, just add a .terserrc file with this content.

```json
{
 "ecma": 6,
 "output": {
   "ascii_only": true
  }
}
```

This is an adaptation of @marian-klühspies response https://stackoverflow.com/a/58528858/2920671

Answer (score 1):

Had this error get thrown after editing working source code in WordPad. When I saved the file in WordPad, the encoding was lost. To fix it, open the same file in NotePad, Save as,  and specify "UTF-8" in the Encoding drop down menu next to the save button.