# Chrome Extension has a content.js error about UTF-8

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, utf-8, webpack-4

After migration from webpack 3.6.0 to webpack 4.29.6 and migrate to babel-loader 8.0.0-beta.6 (from 7.1.5) I see the error:

> Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not load file 'content.js' for content script. It isn't UTF-8 encoded.

I did nothing with code, I only have updated versions in package.json.

So, my application doesn't work. Where is the problem here?

Comment: Start by verifying that manually re-saving the file in UTF8 solves the problem.

Comment: Doesn't help that decision. The same error.

Comment: Sounds like [Chrome says my content script isn't UTF-8](//stackoverflow.com/q/49979397). Try also googling the error message text for more solutions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome says my content script isn't UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49979397/chrome-says-my-content-script-isnt-utf-8)

Answer (score 5):

It looks like the JavaScript code somewhere contains non-ASCII characters and Chrome doesn't like the way they are handled when the code gets minified. If you use `terser-webpack-plugin` you can add an option to handle this:

```js
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        terserOptions: {
          output: { ascii_only: true },
        },
      }),
    ],
  },
  ...
};
```

Heres a relevant issue in terser repo ([non-ASCII characters get converted to UTF-8](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin/issues/107)).